# Different Rates of Twins Across Different Races?

Tags: evolution, humans, reproduction

I heard recently that different races have different rates of twins/other multiple births, with individuals of Asian descent being the least likely to have multiple births, while those of African descent are the most likely. Is this true, and if it is, what evolutionary factors might have caused this so I can extrapolate how frequently my human races in a planned world of mine would produce multiple births.

Comment: Are you aware that human races have no scientific base? But that's not enough to make it a worldbuilding question.

Comment: In other words, "is there a genetic base for twin birth rates?" is a question for biology or medicine.

Comment: @L.Dutch - It's true that our dividing lines are arbitrary, but races do in fact have different genes. And there are studies that back up Preg-Fan's idea. (See the link in my answer below for one example)

Comment: It's a real world stuff question, and therefore on topic. This line of inquiry can easily springboard into a consideration of how different ethnicities (i.e., "races") might behave in a subcreated world.

Answer (score 3):

[It is true.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1716641/?page=13) Socio-economic status seems to explain part of the difference, but not all of it. It would appear that there is a genetic component. There's no way for us to *know* what evolutionary factors may cause this, but we can take some educated guesses. Twins are hereditary, which simplifies things. Anything that makes twins less likely to survive and/or reproduce would limit their occurrence, and anything that helps them survive and/or reproduce would make them more prominent. I'll take a stab at natural and man-made factors that could change the birth-rate of twins over time.

Natural: Harsh environments of any kind will limit the rate of twins, while resource-rich environments will raise it. This is because raising 2 children requires more resources than 1. [citation needed] If the environment does not provide enough resources to safely raise 2 children simultaneously, it is likely that 1 twin will die. Depending on the parents' ability to make difficult choices, both may die. Twins are also more likely to have birth complications, which are more difficult to recover from (for the children and mother) in a resource-poor environment. As society develops, healthcare is also less likely to be high-quality and widely available in resource-poor environments, giving even more of an edge to twins in resource-rich environments. Availability of resources is the only natural factor I can think of.

Man-made: Society can have a huge impact on twins. I have heard of a culture, (can't remember if it was real or fictional) in which only the healthier twin was allowed to live. That's a 50% death rate right off the bat for twins. You could have a culture that believes twins are a sign of evil spirits interfering with the child, and they could kill one or both as a result. (Maybe they believe 1 is an imposter, and have some ritual to tell which, or kill both to be safe, or maybe they believe both are tainted and can't be trusted) On the other hand, you could have a culture that idolizes twins, either as celebrities or as avatars of the gods. They would protect them as a result, and the twins would likely have many sexual partners, either because of their fame or because of rituals or social customs that encourage polygamy where twins are concerned. If  female twins in the culture (I believe the twin gene is passed through women) commonly had 20+ children, while non-twins only had 1-3, or even up to 10, it would only take a few generations for the twin birth rate to rise significantly. If the culture continued that way for long enough, twins may even become common.

Comment: all the factor you account against twin are widely common in Africa rather than in Asia, so how comes twin births are more common in Africa than in Asia, as you stated?

Comment: @L.Dutch, the conclusion of the study was that white races have more twin births than non-white. Statistically, Asians have fewer twin births, but I believe the study could not determine that the difference for Asians was genetically-related. I could be wrong. I skimmed all but the conclusion and the introduction. All of that said, large parts of Africa are resource-poor, but they're also population-poor. There aren't a lot of people living in the Sahara. There ARE a lot living around the rivers.

Comment: @L.Dutch, I also want to add that much of our species' developmental history occurred before our recorded history, and we really don't know if the people we think of as African developed their racial traits in Africa. For many reasons, it's hard to say which races developed while suffering from resource-scarcity, and we also don't know how their cultures may have countered the effects or exacerbated them.

Comment: @L.Dutch Last comment on this, I swear! My previous comments aside, I agree that you have a good counterpoint, there. I would have expected African environments to lead to fewer twins and Asian environments to lead to more. (And it seems likely that "Africans" developed in, or at least near, Africa, and "Asians" in or near the more populated Asian territories.)